# My function returns a annoying zero to my output

Tags: c

My function (max_of_four) needs the `return;` code but by adding it, I also get a zero to my output which I don't want. I only want the content of int c (the number 6) to be printed.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){

    if ((c > a) && (c > b) && (c > d)) {
        printf("%d", c);
    }
return ;
}


int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me to get just the integer c (6) printed, without the zero (it looks like 60 now).

Comment: Your function is defined to return something. It is currently returning nothing. Furthermore, the logic is incomplete as the only case it checks for is if `c` is the largest and not if any of the other values are largest.

Comment: Your function invokes *undefined behavior* - you aren't returning anything from `max_of_four`

Comment: You don't want to print inside of the function.  You instead want to return the value of which ever parameter is largest.

Comment: I know that the function only checks C. But I just wanted to check if it works for so long. Which it does not because I get a zero as output from somewhere. I get a 6 from the max_of_four function.

Comment: The 0 comes from this: `printf("%d", ans);`. Because as we told you the function is not returning a value but the caller is using the return value.

Comment: Replace all your printfs with more verbose messages.   eg `printf("in main, ans = %d\n", ans)` and `printf("in max_of_four, c = %d\n", c)` and you will see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem (assuming that we want to keep your logic for max_of_four intact which seems wrong):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

void max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    // You print the answer here but don't return anything.
    // main() does not expect anything when calling max_of_four(..)
    if ((c > a) && (c > b) && (c > d)) {
        printf("%d", c);
    }
}


int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    return 0;
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    // You don't print the answer here but just return the
    // value of c. Please note, you still don't know what to do
    // when c does not satisfy the condition
    if ((c > a) && (c > b) && (c > d)) {
        return c;
    }
}


int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! I found the solution to my problem in your comment. It was the returning of the integer c ( "if ((c > a) && (c > b) && (c > d)) {
        return c;").

So the code works now as intended and the function code looks like this:
"int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    int result = 0;
    if ((c > a) && (c > b) && (c > d)) {
        return c;
    } else if ((a > b) && (a > c) && (a > d)){
        return a;
    } else if ((b > a) && (b > c) && (b > d)){
        return b;
    } else if ((d > a) && (d > b) && (d > c)){
        return d;
    }"

Answer (score 2):

In `max_of_four`, you have [only] `return;`. You need a `return` that returns a *value*

You probably don't want a `printf` in the function (i.e.) it's a debug `printf`.

If we believe the name of your function, the function has to compare all values for maximum.

Here's some refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

int
max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int m = a;

    if (b > m)
        m = b;

    if (c > m)
        m = c;

    if (d > m)
        m = d;

    return m;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);

    printf("%d\n", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okey So I got it working thanks to thanatonian2311. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
Add `int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)` here.
*/

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    int result = 0;
    if ((c > a) && (c > b) && (c > d)) {
        return c;
    } else if ((a > b) && (a > c) && (a > d)){
        return a;
    } else if ((b > a) && (b > c) && (b > d)){
        return b;
    } else if ((d > a) && (d > b) && (d > c)){
        return d;
    }

return result;
}


int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `max_of_four(2,2,2,2)` returns 0.  Was this intended?